# Setting long String to UILabel Freezing my app with undetected error

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uilabel, swift4.2

(I use https://www.charactercountonline.com to count my string, then my string is 2253 characters)
I want to set UILabel with long string, but my app keep getting freeze without error log in xcode.

I have tried setting up UILabel with shorter string, and it succeeded! I have tried using `DispatchQueue` while setting up UILabel, but it keep freezing too without showing error log.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
           contentLabel.text = text  }
```

How can i fix it? It makes me stuck for a few days.

Edit :
I've tried to hardcode value of string.
[image: this is exactly the line where problem occured]
this is exactly the line where problem occured

Comment: Have you tried putting  the exception breakpoint to detect the exact location of crash?

Comment: @PGDev yes i have. The problem exactly occured in the code that I showed above. After that, app is freezing. Sorry i mean my app is freezing not crashing.

Comment: And why are you giving the delay of 1.0 sec?

Comment: Because when i didn't give delay, it didn't work. then, I think if I give it delay, it will work.  but nothing happened

Comment: Your code has no runtime issues except a minor compiling issue i.e, `self.contentLabel.text` instead of `contentLabel.text`. Please show more/actual code to reproduce the issue along with the `error` log.

Comment: @Kamran i've written that there's no error log. 
Please see my question again, i've attached screenshot of PGDev solution. I've tried putting breakpoint, and this is the only line that caused my app freezing.

Comment: maybe use textView

Comment: @diana `String` value is fine and shouldn't create an issue. Still i don't see any issue  for freezing behavior. Would it be possible to create an example project and share somewhere on `git`?

Comment: You can try UITextView similar as UILabel. I'm not sure UITextView will solve your problem. I also faced same problem long time ago and that time I used multiple UILabel to solve that problem. I think UILabel have limit of words to show thats why it keeps freezing the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DispatchQueue.main.async` without any *delay*, i.e.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {[weak self] in
    self?.contentLabel.text = text
}
```

The above code is working perfectly fine for any length `text`.